# Can't run test after installing cypress-if plugin

Tags: cypress, cypress-custom-commands

Installing the cypress-if plugin and adding import "cypress-if" to the `e2e` file is causing the test to fail.

The error message returned is:

```
> Cannot overwite the get query. Queries can only be overwritten with Cypress.Commands.overwriteQuery().
```

Until now, I didn't use it yet in spec test. :(

[image: Cypress error output]

How can I resolve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can't resolve it, unfortunately Cypress dropped the feature for overwriting the get query after version `11.2.0`.

We must wait until [this issue](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-if/issues/58) is resolved. You can subscribe to the issue and watch the progress.

If you really want to use it, you can drop to `11.2.0` version. If not, re-write the `.if()` occurrences (if you have any) to "normal" Cypress by following [this guide](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/upgrade-cypress-v9-to-v12/), and remove the `cypress-if` plugin until it becomes available again.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're seeing is due to a breakage in the cypress-if plugin caused by changes in Cypress 12 ([cypress-if#58](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-if/issues/58)).  Due to the issue, the cypress-if plugin no longer worked for versions of Cypress starting with 12.0.0.  This was [fixed](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-if/issues/58#issuecomment-1669638680) in cypress-if plugin version 1.10.5.

Either upgrading the cypress-if version to 1.10.5 or later, or downgrading Cypress to 11.x would fix the issue.

Comment: Do you mean "downgrading Cypress to 9.x would fix"?

Comment: @Jackson.J.Lamb No, I mean downgrading Cypress from 12.x to 11.x.